# Чистка mysql таблицы раз в сутки через crontab

Tags: mysql, cron, crontab

на хостинге такое окно
[image]

подскажите, что туда написать, чтобы выполнялся запрос к БД с удалением всех строк из таблицы `clicks`

Comment: У вашего хостера должен быть faq по работе с панелью управления сайтами, посмотрите там.

Answer (score 2):

например:

```
echo "delete from таблица" | mysql -u пользователь -pпароль база-данных
```